# Connect user to MVC3 application without login form (Single Sign On)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, active-directory, asp.net-membership, single-sign-on

I want to know if it's possible to connect users to my application using `Active directory`login and password but without ask the users to re-enter them.

What i actually do :(disabled `anonymous auth`/enabled `Win auth`)

1- the users poweron their desktop and enter their login and password (Active directory)

2- open the application and re-enter the same login/password (again)

I want to avoid the second step, and get the information i need from the session(the name, username...)

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the browser supports ntlm they shouldn't get prompted.

here is an article on how to do this.
[Authenticating Users with Windows Authentication](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs)

For support in specific browsers search:

"ntlm firefox"
"ntlm chrome"

etc...

To get the actual users username (User.Identity.Name) you see: [HttpContext.User Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx)

see also:
[IIdentity Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity.aspx)

Comment: As i wrote before, the windows authentification is enabled. I try to connect with the three popular web browser(IE,Chrome,Firefox) but all of them show me the login form. Can you please tell me how to enable the NTLM function on this browsers ?